# Sharepoint 2013: init.js in "use strict" mode

Tags: javascript, master-page

`init.js` started throwing errors after changing `http-equiv` `meta` tag.

It looks like strict mode is being enforced on `init.js` but can't see `"use strict"` anywhere.

Error:

Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode

Faulting code:

```
function ULSOnError(b,c,a) {
    return ULSSendExceptionImpl(b,c,a,ULSOnError.caller)
}
```

Comment: Can it be a browser issue? Maybe this link helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050/inconsistent-scope-of-use-strict-on-different-web-browsers-concerning-argumen

Comment: That question refers to difference in how different browsers handle accessing caller of a strict function in a non-strict area of code. Here the function and the caller are contained in init.js

Comment: Reverted the changes to master page and the problem persists. Still can't find any "use strict" literal.